# Every homogeneous polynomial of positive degree has nontrivial zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field, and $n,m \geq 1$. If $F(T_0,T_1,...,T_n)$ is an homogeneous polynomial of degree m, then $F$ has nontrivial zeros.

I would like to prove the previous statement using algebraic geometry arguments. I know it's possibile to show it via induction on $n$, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143201/homogeneous-polynomial-over-algebraically-closed-field-has-non-trivial-zero).

Maybe it follows directly from Projective (or affine) Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, but I cannot find any correct attempt.

If I assume, on the contrary, that $V(F)=\{(u_0:u_1:\cdots:u_n)\in \mathbb{P}^n\,\,:\,\,F(u_0,...,u_n)=0\}=\emptyset$, then by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz,  exist $k\geq 1$ such that the principal ideal generated by $F$ contains the k-th power of the irrelevant ideal $R^{+}=(T_0,...,T_n)$. Is it possible from this to show a contradiction??

Hope someone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to show a contradiction from here. If $(F)$ contains $(R^+)^k$, then it must contain $T_i^k$ for all $i$. If you write out what this means in terms of divisibility relations, you should be able to see what goes wrong. (More details spoilered below.)

> Specifically, $F$ must divide $T_i^k$ for all $i$, which is nonsense, since the only elements of $R$ which do this are the constants.

Comment: yes, right, of course! thanks a lot!